# Regex to match URL ending with _F<XX>_C<XX>

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

In the URL, _F and C are fixed and XX are dynamic integers.

I have tried these patterns:

```
^_F[\d+]_C[\d+]$
```

Example URLs are :

```
_F23_C456

_F345_C1
```

I am trying to match this regex in urls.py of django.

Comment: `^_F(\d+)_C(\d+)$` ?

Comment: What is the problem you have ?

Comment: What's with the square brackets - what are you expecting them to do, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `+` outside the character class and either remove the start-of-string anchor `^`, or insert `.*` after it:

```
^.*_F\d+_C\d+$
```

Or

```
_F\d+_C\d+$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fC2iC6/1)

Inside the character class, `+` is treated literally, not as a quantifier, and loses its *match 1 or more occurrences* meaning. And your regex matches beginning of string, an underscore,  `F`, one digit or `+`, an underscore, `C`, one digit or `+` and the end of string.

Comment: That is why I always add a note that it is not a good practice to place single shorthand classes into character classes. `[\d]` is equal to `\d`, but there are a lot of people who use character classes like that.

Comment: I think you  need to remove `^` since OP is trying to match "url **ending** with `_F<XX>_C<XX>`".

Comment: You can check this quickly using regex checking sites, such as http://regexpal.com.

Comment: @ChakerBenhamed: Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @ChakerBenhamed: regexpal.com is good for checking JS regex flavor, I'd prefer [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) for Python-compatible regexps. Optionally, [debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com) for visualization.